# Include Header/footer in CI3

Tags: php, web, codeigniter-3

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Mahasiswa extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('m_mahasiswa');
        }
        
    public function index()
    {
    
    $data['data_mahasiswa'] = $this->m_mahasiswa->data_mahasiswa();
    $this->load->view('template/header.php', $data);
    $this->load->view('home/index.php', $data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer.php', $data);
    }
```

Hello, is it possible to make footer and header can be used everytime?

It gave me uncaught exception undefined constant "BASEURL"

Answer (score 0):

I may have a helpful solution for you! I created a VScode extension about two years ago that can speed up your `codeigniter 3` development by providing important commands. One of its useful features is called `Create Template`, which can generate a library and several files in the views, including a template, header, footer, and navigation files. You can also add your own files by following its structure.

The name of this extension is [Codeigniter 3 Files Creator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SyedMuradAliShah.codeigniter-3-files-creator). You can search for it in the VScode Extensions or download it directly from the visual studio marketplace.